# datagrid text field that trigger GridView1_RowCommand event

Tags: asp.net, datagrid

I have a datagrid where I want to have a filed display status as text and trigger a command event so I can handle it server side just like asp:ButtonField do.

My failing code is:

```
<asp:ButtonField CommandName="CallHist" 
ButtonType="Button" Text ="<%#GetJobs(Eval("currStatus"))%>" >
</asp:ButtonField>
```

I get error:

> Literal content ('" >') is not allowed within a
>   'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ButtonField'.

I am trying to alter existing workign ButtonFields:

```
<asp:ButtonField CommandName="editRecord" ControlStyle-Height="16px" ControlStyle-Width ="16px" ButtonType="image" ImageUrl="images/edit-icon.png">
                                            </asp:ButtonField>

                                            <asp:ButtonField CommandName="deleteRecord" ControlStyle-Height="16px" ControlStyle-Width ="16px" ButtonType="Image"  ImageUrl="images/close-icon.png">
                                            </asp:ButtonField>
```

I have also tried, with no luck, using `<asp:TemplateField>`

How can i get a field to display data and be a clickable / fired event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ButtonField` does not support binding expressions. You can replace it by a `TemplateField` with a LinkButton or a Button in its `ItemTemplate`. In the data-binding expression of the `Text` property, you should replace the outer double quotes by single quotes to avoid the conflict with the inner double quotes:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" CommandName="CallHist" Text='<%# GetJobs(Eval("currStatus")) %>' CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: how can i get this to pass the dataKey (aka the id of the row) to the .cs event so i can do something like this: protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
            if (e.CommandName.Equals("detail"))

Comment: You can bind  `CommandArgument` to the ID field. I updated my answer to show that. You can adjust the code to fit your actual ID field name.